# Movement system not working when teleport works, teleport doesn't work when movement works

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, steamvr

So i have a player prefab (from steamVR) and ive attached two hands to it, in place of the old hands, one of the hands is a gun and works perfectly as expected, the other hand is completely shot and I've spent the last 2 hours de-bugging to no avail. I have a script, that  uses the players direction of the controller, and the direction of the thumb stick to move, this is attached to the left controller, and is what breaks the teleport when it works.

I can get the movement working perfectly, to the sacrifice of my teleport system (Teleport works, except for height, cant teleport to places above where i currently am, just puts me below it in correlation. It's also worth noting that im using steamvr's teleport prefab too.

Here's the set-up of it working, when the controller isn't working:

Player Prefab: https://gyazo.com/0d52edf219b4a16c1f842818dbafc89a

Hand: https://gyazo.com/5089b750520dcf6f6b8fe5bd899ef1cb

Here's the set-up when teleport isn't properly working
Player Prefab: (Same as before)
Hand: https://gyazo.com/5cc125244e3ae3911ae14f23d2e187fd

And here's the code for the movement:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

public class Vrtouchmove : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField]
private Transform camera;

private Valve.VR.EVRButtonId touchpad = 
Valve.VR.EVRButtonId.k_EButton_SteamVR_Touchpad;

private SteamVR_Controller.Device controller { get { return 
SteamVR_Controller.Input((int)trackedObj.index);  } }
private SteamVR_TrackedObject trackedObj;

private Vector2 axis = Vector2.zero;


void Start()
{
    trackedObj = GetComponent <SteamVR_TrackedObject>();
}

void Update ()
{
    if (controller == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Controller not Set");
        return;
    }

    var device = SteamVR_Controller.Input((int)trackedObj.index);

    if (controller.GetTouch(touchpad))
    {
        axis = device.GetAxis(Valve.VR.EVRButtonId.k_EButton_Axis0);

        if (camera != null)
        {
            camera.position += (transform.right * axis.x + transform.forward * axis.y) 
* Time.deltaTime;
           camera.position = new Vector3(camera.position.x, 0, camera.position.z);
        }
    }
    }

 }
```

I'm stumped as to why it's not working, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Update` method, if the input is "touchpad" and the camera is not null, then you're setting the y value of camera the to 0.

```
camera.position = new Vector3(camera.position.x, 0, camera.position.z);
```

Comment: Sorry, I've only just seen this! So would adding this line of code fix my height interpretation issue be fixed? Currently not with my VR headset but can still make the change